# Get total of a field grouped by date and another field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with data as follows,

```
detectDate      |isp    |infection  | count
--------------------------------------
2012-10-02 01:00|aaaa   |malware    |3
2012-10-02 01:30|bbbb   |malware    |2
2012-10-02 01:33|bbbb   |spy-eye    |2
2012-10-02 01:45|aaaa   |DDos       |1
2012-10-03 01:50|cccc   |malware    |2
2012-10-03 02:00|dddd   |TDSS       |2
2012-10-03 04:50|dddd   |TDSS       |3
```

I need to get an out put like this, grouped by date and infection like so,

```
detectDate      |infection  | count
--------------------------------------
2012-10-02      |malware    |5
2012-10-02      |spy-eye    |2
2012-10-02      |DDos       |1
2012-10-03      |malware    |2
2012-10-03      |TDSS       |5
```

I know how to use group in general but not his far :( can you please help me I need to group by date and infection and get the total of the count field as shown.

Comment: Note that there is a little bit mistake in your expected output: `count of malware for detectDate 2012-10-02 should be 5 instead of 6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function to sum `count` column and use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to group by only date.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(detectDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS detectDate
      ,infection 
      ,SUM(`COUNT`) as `count`
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(detectDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), infection
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c51b8/8)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) mySql function to extract date part from date/time column:

```
select DATE(detectDate),infection, sum(count) 
from t group by DATE(detectDate),infection
order by  DATE(detectDate);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply this works tooo :) but @hims056 answer gives the date in the format i need :) . much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

```
select detectDate, infection, sum(count) as count
from table_name
group by detectDate, infection
```

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answers.

Comment: the question was solved, anyway thank you very much for the reply :)